# What software can copy the whole hard drive with Operating System to DVD-R, and be able to "refresh the machine" using the DVD-R?

Tags: clone, disk-image

What software can take a snapshot of a Win XP or Win 7 machine -- burning all files into a DVD-R, and then

1. be able to boot from that DVD-R
2. can restore the whole machine back to that state stored inside the DVD-R?

Maybe for Win XP, it is easier as the OS can be just 1 or 2GB on the hard drive, but for Win 7, a fresh installation is already 16GB on the hard drive, so it will need several DVD-R to take the snapshot?  thanks.

(any of these software are open source?)

Comment: use synchronisation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is software out there that can do exactly what you're asking!

---

1. [DriveImageXML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) FREE
2. [NortonGhost](http://www.symantec.com/norton/ghost) NOT FREE

---

These both support boot from CD.

Comment: thanks.  do they back up your pagefile and hibernation files too?  say if you boot from those DVD-R and then ... will it create pagefile and put on your hard disk when running?

Comment: It will backup whatever state your drive is in when you perform the backup. That includes the pagefile and hibernationfile if your drive is in a hibernated state.